# How to "ignore" syncing of specific photos with Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos, synchronization

I have Google Photos on my iOS device. It has successfully synced most of my photos, but there are about 120 old photos that for one reason or the other it cannot sync (it doesn't give me specifics, it just tells me it cannot sync the photo).

I don't much care if those photos actually get synced, but I would like to remove them from the queue of photos to be synced (they never go away).  I would like to tell Google Photos to just "ignore" those photos, but I cannot find a way to do this.

I considered deleting the photo from Google Photos, but it wanted to also delete the photo from my iOS device when I performed this action, and I do not consider this an acceptable alternative.

Is there a way to instruct Google Photos to ignore a photo when attempting to sync? (bonus if it can be done in bulk)